# VueJs typescript recursive child components (throws [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, recursion

I am working on a dynamic form generated by a DataTypeObject (dto).
Now I am stuck on the following warning while creating recursive components,
that points to al list of components with the same type than it´s parent:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Here are the code snippets:

The first is the , that desides based on that dto.type what type of component should be shown.

```
<template>
  <div class="field">
    <NumberInputComponent
      v-if="dto.type == 'NumberInput'"
      v-bind:dto="dto"
    ></NumberInputComponent>
    ...
    <FieldGroupComponent
      v-if="dto.type == 'FieldGroup'"
      v-bind:dto="dto"
    ></FieldGroupComponent>
    ...
    <TextFieldComponent
      v-if="dto.type == 'TextField'"
      v-bind:dto="dto"
    ></TextFieldComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch, Emit } from "vue-property-decorator";
import NumberInputComponent from "./NumberInput/NumberInput.vue";
import TextFieldComponent from "./TextField/TextField.vue";
...
import FieldGroupComponent from "./FieldGroup/FieldGroup.vue";
import { Field } from "./Field.dto";
@Component({
  name: 'FieldComponent',
  components: {
    NumberInputComponent,
    TextFieldComponent,
    ...
    FieldGroupComponent
  },
})
export default class FieldComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop() private dto!: Field;
  ...
}
</script>
```

The  is for grouping other fields inside a logical group:

```
<template>
  <div class="field-group">
    <FieldComponent
      v-for="(field, index) in dto.fields"
      :key="index"
      v-bind:dto="field"
    ></FieldComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Emit } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { FieldGroup } from "./FieldGroup.dto";
import FieldComponent from "../Field.vue";

@Component({
  name: "FieldGroupComponent",
  components: {
    FieldComponent,
  },
})
export default class FieldGroupComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop() public dto!: FieldGroup;
}
</script>
```

If I do not reload the page after saving a change, The child fields are visible
but after reloading they hide.
The Error disapears while commenting out the  inside the FieldGroup.

I tryed to recreate this recursion error but in another recursion everything works.
Even without setting the name property.

Thanks to everyone trying to help us.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer.
The Error is, that the FieldComponent is undefined inside the GroupFieldComponent before Created.
So I had to remove it from the Component-Decorator and import it inside the beforeCreate-function

```
beforeCreate () {
  if(this.$options.components)
  this.$options.components.FieldComponent = require('../Field.vue').default
}
```

I found the answer inside this [vueJs Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components)